# Can you fade in and out particles in blender eevee?

Tags: materials, particles, eevee-render-engine

I have looked for a way to fade in and out particles in blender eevee, but people say particle info node is incompatible with eevee. Does anyone know of a different method?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what you mean when you say "fade in and out"? Do you mean fade over time, over distance, fade in, fade out, both, etc...? Also, are you using emitted particles or hair, and are they native particles or instanced objects?

Comment: Fade as in over time. I'm using objects as particles. I want them to fade after a set amount of time instead of just disappearing instantly. I hope that has made it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of one way to do it in EEVEE. The idea is to use an object as the base for a particle instance, then to give that object a material that fades in and out over time.

The setup for the material is this - The primary factor of this is that you can type `#frame` into the field of a value node, and it will then provide the value of the frame position at any given point. I used some math to make it oscillate, and to slow it down a little. The idea is to use the `sine` of the frame number as a Mix Factor between the regular material (particle color) and a Transparent Shader, thus making it fade in and out. You can adjust the division number to speed up or slow down the fade. Lastly, don't forget to change the Blend Mode.

[image: FadeParticles]

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll be sure to give it a try!

Comment: Just for clarification: do you want to fade with _time_ or _lifetime/age_ of the particles? With the above material, each particle will have the exact same value on each frame. So on frame 30 the _time_ for each particle is 30. With the _Partcile Info_ node a particle born on frame 1 would have an _age_ of 30, but another born on frame 21 would have an _age_ of 10. So materials created on age and/or lifetime would take the time of the particle's existence into account - which is what Eevee can't do. Materials related to frames make all particles the same at any time of the animation.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer. I wanted to make dust disappear overtime, depending on how long it had been 'alive'.